# Change the div content according to link selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have listed my div details.I want to know how to change the content of **main div** by using the *link* and load the **child div** in the **main div**.

```
link 1 : link 2: link 3 :link 4
```

---

```
<div id="main">
    <div>diplay1</div>
    <div>diplay2</div>
    <div>diplay3</div>
    <div>diplay4</div>
</div>
```

Please advice me.

Comment: Have you tried any code? This is possible with JS or Jquery...

Comment: What do you mean by _change the content of main div by using the link_?

Comment: They already seem to be in the `main div`. Are you looking for something like `hide/show` ?

Comment: @DKM I want to display only one child div in the main Div based upon the link selection.I want to hide other div' hide

Comment: Have you heard of the [jQuery UI Tabs plugin](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and does it possibly accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use JS / JQuery , CSS and classes to achieve that.

HTML with classes, href, and custom attribute.

```
<a class="linked" data-link="content1" href="#">Link1</a>
<a class="linked" data-link="content2" href="#">Link2</a>
<a class="linked" data-link="content3" href="#">Link3</a>

<div id="main">
    <div class="content1">diplay1</div>
    <div class="content2">diplay2</div>
    <div class="content3">diplay3</div>
</div>
```

JQuery code

```
$('a.linked').on('click', function(e){
    $('div.' + $(this).attr('data-link')).show().siblings().hide();
    /* this will select and show div with class 
       which is in the custom attribute data-link of the clicked link. 
       Then it will select all of its sibling elements 
       i.e. all within this parent and no children if any 
       except the first selected div and will hide them. */
});
```

CSS styles

```
#main *{
    display:none;
}
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GC9dZ/)**

Answer (score 2):

Using this format

```
<div id="main">
    <div>diplay1</div>
    <div>diplay2</div>
    <div>diplay3</div>
    <div>diplay4<div>ok</div></div>
</div>

<div>
  <a href='javascript:;' class='link'>1</a>
  <a href='javascript:;' class='link'>2</a>
  <a href='javascript:;' class='link'>3</a>
  <a href='javascript:;' class='link'>4</a>
</div>
```

Then with a small script

```
$('.link').click(function(){
   $('#main > div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/trDXc/1/)

Comment: Can you please explain me a little of these code $('#main div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show(); ?

Comment: @captain  `$('#main div').hide()` will select and hide all the `divs` inside `#main`. `eq()` is a jQuery selector that selects the element from a specific `index`. Since the `a` and the `#main divs` have the same index it is easier to select the div from main with the same index

Comment: It will also hide all the children divs if there is a hierarchy, which may also mess up with the index. `#main > div` direct children selector will be better option.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/C27Vz/63/)

```
$('#main a').click(function() {
    $('div:not(#main)').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    return false;
});
```